# Normal View with multi language website

Tags: views, 7, forms

I have a normal view on multi language site and add a field Called website the field is displayed on en language but does not show in the another language
[image]

How i can fix this problem

Comment: Are you sure the relevant content is translated?  Are you using node or entity translation?

Comment: when i use this link localhost/apig/ar/admin/structure/views/view/car_rentals/edit it is display but the out side of this view does not appear

Comment: when you filter on Content language being equal to the logged in user's language, you are telling Views to show content only in that language, so, if something isn't in that language, it will be filtered out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all . my problem is come from the model is called [views i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews) cuase it is override the result to anther that i have translate it